# How to join a table with itself based on a foreign key in same table?

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a SQL table as follows:

```
Id | Name | Email        | Id_manager
---+------+--------------+------------
1  | Jon  | jon@foo.com  |    2
2  | Mike | mike@foo.com |    2
2  | Bar  | bar@foo.com  |    1
```

So here Jon is the manager of Bar and mike is the manager of John and himself. So `Id_manager` is a foreign key that references the same table.

I need to return a new table containing the following columns

```
Name, Email, Manager_Name
```

But I have no clue how to get the name of the manager using a SQL operation. Should I use a join? If so how can I do it in this case?

Comment: FKs & other constraints are not needed to query, they just might make some  expressions return the same values as expressions that you could have used anyway. PS (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. For code questions give a [mre]. Show parts you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a self-join indeed:

```
select t.name, t.email, m.name as manager_name
from mytable t
inner join mytable m on m.id = t.id_manager
```

If there are employees without a manager, you might want to use `left join` instead of `inner join` to avoid filtering them out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer can also be put in this way:

```
select t1.name, t1.email, t2.name as manager_name from mytable t1, mytable t2
where t1.id_manager = t2.id
```

I think the Id column should be unique, so I change the Id of Bar from 2 to 3.
The following can tell you the result when the id_manager column in t1 is equal to the Id column in t2.

```
t1                                   t2
Id|Name|Email       |Id_manager      Id|Name|Email       |Id_manager
1 |Jon |jon@foo.com |2               2 |Mike|mike@foo.com|2
2 |Mike|mike@foo.com|2               2 |Mike|mike@foo.com|2
3 |Bar|bar@foo.com  |1               1 |Jon |jon@foo.com |2
```